# Sidekiq superworkers testing mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, sidekiq

I'm using sidekiq-superworkers and sidekiq under a project I'm currently working. I have set Sidekiq::Testing.inline! under spec_helper for my integration tests, is there anything similar on superworkers? I need to run workers and wait for they to finish in order to perform some asserts, how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Superworker does not have any way to specify conditions inside it's `create` block.

I had a similar problem where I had to wait for a set of jobs to complete before performing some actions and I went ahead with using [sidekiq_status](https://github.com/cryo28/sidekiq_status).

The basic idea is that you collect all the job ids of the jobs you launch and then poll if any of the job is still processing before performing the next action.

Eg:

```
job_pool = []
(1..100).each do
  # Collect all the job ids that you have launched.
  job_pool.push SomeWorker.perform_async
end

jobs_are_working = true
while jobs_are_working
  # Wait as long as at least one job is working or waiting
  waiting_job = job_pool.detect do |job_id|
    job_status = SidekiqStatus::Container.load(job_id).status
    job_status == "waiting" || job_status == "working"
  end
end
```

It might be a good idea to wrap the whole waiting part inside a Timeout block so that you don't get stuck indefinitely.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but in my case i need very complex workflows and i don't want to risk writing custom code by myself by time matters. I ended up stubbing the Workers flow as mere sidekiq workers under integration test